# Can't install 14.04 (32bit) dual boot with Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I've made a Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit install DVD.  When I boot it on my Lenovo laptop I don't get the dual boot option, only 'Replace' or 'Something else'.  Help!

I chose 32 bit because the laptop is a 32 bit machine - is this the right choice?

I don't think I have any drive partitions at present.  Thanks guys :)

Comment: The something else option would let you dual boot. How comfortable are you editing partitions/setting up drives? Slightly off topic but any reason why you chose the 32 bit version?

Comment: When you choose Something Else, you're being presented  a partitioning utility. Please add a screenshot of this as edit to your question.

Comment: The reasons why you do not get the "Install alongside Windows" could vary. While trying Ubuntu, open a terminal and type `sudo fdisk -l`. This will tell us if you already have too many primary partitions (max. 4).

Answer (score 0):

Use 'something else'.

Go through the answer [*here*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) by [@danatela](https://askubuntu.com/users/171636/danatela) with heading 'If you have blank disk':